# Hot tub, new pump, but jets won't work

Tags: hot-tub

Have a 10 yr old Four Winds, KeyWest model spa, with a Balboa GS300 control board.  Spa was working great until one day the pump just made a loud, constant hum.

Bought new AquaFlo 230v pump and installed.  Bled air to ensure no airlock, but when powering up spa, pump does not start.  Control panel shows no error, but during Priming period, pressing the jets button just make the relay click, but motor wont start.  Power at pump is correct.

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 1):

If the power at the pump is correct you may have a bad pump. To verify, check the following 3 things:

1. There are usually fuses to protect the wiring. Are they good?
2. Are the motor leads correct (low voltage, high voltage)? If not connected properly the stator windings wont spin the rotor.
3. Is the startup capacitor good (where applicable)?

Whatever you do don't dry spin the pump (power without water) or you will damage the shaft seal (pump to motor) and it will leak.